# What's the point of HTML forms `name` attribute?

Tags: html, forms

What's the point of the `name` attribute on an HTML form? As far as I can tell, you can't read the form name on submission or do anything else with it. Does it serve a purpose?

Comment: took me a while to realize you are only wondering about the `name` attribute on a `<form>` tag, not `name` attributes on `<input>` tags within a `<form>`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In short, and probably oversimplifying a bit: It is used instead of `id` for browsers that don't understand `document.getElementById`.

These days it serves no real purpose. It is a legacy from the early days of the browser wars before the use of `name` to describe how to send control values when a form is submitted and `id` to identify an element within the page was settled.

Comment: Yes, a real answer. Thank you. Didn't know that about browsers not understanding `document.getElementById`.. I guess we can skip those ones, huh?

Answer (score 14):

Once you assign a name to an element, you can refer to that element via `document.name_of_element` throughout your code. It doesn't work to tell when you've got multiple fields of the same name, but it does allow shortcuts like:

```
<form name="myform" ...>

document.myform.submit();
```

instead of

```
document.getElementsByName('myform')[0].submit();
```

Comment: You could do this by ID though, so if that's the only use case it doesn't really matter

Comment: @vaxquis `window.id`, or just `id` since `window` is global, seems to work

Answer (score 13):

From [the specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-form-element):

> The `name` attribute represents the `form`'s name within the [`forms`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#dom-document-forms) collection.

Comment: Interesting- I've never had to distinguish forms in a collection before- perhaps this is the real use case?

Comment: @Yarin — You can use `id` for that.

Comment: @Quentin- ok, so this is another superflous use case apparently

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157145/discussion-between-vaxquis-and-quentin).

Comment: @Yarin you can use `name` to distinguish semantics of forms, and `id` to select them in CSS. I assume that's the WHATWG idea here.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what [MDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs) has to say about it:

> **`name`** 
> The name of the form. In HTML 4, its use is deprecated (`id` should be used instead). It must be unique among the forms in a document and not just an empty string in HTML 5.

(from [<form>, Attributes, *name*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-name))

I find it slightly confusing that specifies that it must be unique, non-empty string in HTML 5 when it was deprecated in HTML 4. (I'd guess that requirement only applies if the `name` attribute is specified at all?). But I think it's safe to say that any purpose it once served has been superseded by the `id` attribute.

Comment: Good answer I think. This was the only conclusion I could come to as well, after reading the MDN docs.

Comment: A couple of elements and attributes which were deprecated in HTML4 made a comeback with a slightly different meaning in HTML5. I think `small` is one of those, where the original meaning was just for size, but now it has taken on a semantic meaning such as “fine print”. I haven’t found any more on this but the `name` attribute may also have been redefined in HTML5.

Comment: When you go to the MDN page linked above, the statement "The name of the form. In HTML 4, its use is deprecated..." can no longer be found.

Answer (score 1):

`name` attribute is not completely redundant vis-à-vis `id`.  As aforementioned, it useful with `<forms>`, but less known is that it can also be used with with any `HTMLCollection`, such as the `children` property of any DOM element.

`HTMLCollection`, in additional to be a array-like object, will have named properties commensurate with any named members (or the first occurrence in case of non-unique name).  It is useful to retrieve specific named nodes.

For example, in the following example HTML:

```
<div id='person1'>
   <span name='firstname'>John</span>
   <span name='lastname'>Doe</span>
   <span name='middlename'></span>
</div>

<div id='person2'>
   <span name='firstname'>Jane</span>
   <span name='lastname'>Doe</span>
   <span name='middlename'></span>
</div>
```

by naming each child, one can quickly and efficiently retrieve a named element, such as `lastname`, as such:

```
document.getElementById('person1').children.namedItem('lastname')
```

...and if there is no risk of 'length' being the name of a member element, (being that `length` is a reserved property of `HTMLCollection`), a more terse notation may be used instead:

```
document.getElementById('person1').children.lastname
```

[DOM Living Standard 2019 March 29](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlcollection)

> An HTMLCollection object is a collection of elements...

> The namedItem(key) method, when invoked, must run these steps:
>
> If key is the empty string, return null.
>
> Return the first element in the collection for which at least one of the following is true:
> it has an ID which is key;
> it is in the HTML namespace and has a name attribute whose value is key;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name attribute as an "extra information" attribute - similarly as with a hidden input - but this keeps the extra information tied into the form, which makes it just a little simpler to read/access.

Comment: Don't do that. Hidden inputs contain data which will be submitted to the server. The `name` attribute of a form element won't be. If you want to provide extra data purely for client-side code to access, then the `data-*` attributes are expressly provided for that purpose.