# Is it OK to have multiple HTML forms with the same name?

Tags: html, forms

I have a valid reason for wanting to do this, but it's a long story so I'll forgot trying to explain why and just ask if it's OK to do.

I have a page where I need to have multiple forms with the same name, but I only want the form whose submit button is click to be submitted. For example, the following might be on my page:

```
<form name="input" action="" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

text

<form name="input" action="" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

text

<form name="input" action="" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Is this acceptable?

Comment: http://www.onlinewebcheck.com detects duplicate form name errors in HTML5 documents

Comment: why use `form name` at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946320/whats-the-point-of-html-forms-name-attribute

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Regarding the HTML 4.01 specication, you can use `form` elements with the same `name` attribute, as there is no uniqueness requirement on them. Doing so defeats the purpose of such attributes, though. They are meant for making it easier to refer to forms in client-side scripting: if you have `<form name=foo>`, then `document.foo` refers to that form.

It is undefined what happens when same `name` attribute is used, but what browsers seem to do is to return an array. In your example, `document.foo` would be a 3-element array, with `document.foo[0]` being the first form. But this is not useful, since (assuming there are no other forms in the document) you could use `document.forms[0]`, with a well-defined meaning.

The `name` attribute itself is outdated for `form` elements (but not for form fields, where it keeps being essential). The [HTML 4.01 spec clause on `form`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-FORM) says:

“`name` = cdata [CI]
    This attribute names the element so that it may be referred to from style sheets or scripts. Note. This attribute has been included for backwards compatibility. Applications should use the `id` attribute to identify elements.”

In the HTML5 drafts, even the formal rules disallow the use of the same `name` attribute. The [HTML5 clause on the `name` attribute on `form`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#attr-form-name) says that its value “must be unique amongst the `form` elements in the `forms` collection that it is in, if any”. This is a confusing formulation, but it is safest to assume that it must be unique within the `form` elements of a document.

Comment: The bit about document.foo for the multiple matching names case being undefined, isn't that what section 3.1.4 DOM tree accessors from http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/dom.html#dom-document-namedItem-which to the end of 3.1.4 defines?

Comment: @Alohci, it’s undefined in current specs. The HTML5 drafts define a mechanism for this, but it also imposes a uniqueness requirement.

Comment: Yeah, fair point. Discussions of what's HTML 4, what's HTML5, and what user-agents *do*, given that they don't have separate HTML 4 and HTML5 modes, gets very complicated sometimes.

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is allowed, only `id`'s must be unique. I wouldn't recommend it however, why even put yourself in a position to be confused down the road.

The `name` attribute only defines what each form field element will be represented as when sent to the server.

Comment: The `name` attribute of a `form` element does not affect the data sent to the server. You may have confused it with `name` attributes for form fields.

Answer (score 1):

It is also ok in HTML5. Only the name must be unique inside the form itself.

See the docs: "The value must not be the empty string, and the value must be unique amongst the form elements in the forms collection that it is in, if any."

Comment: This may be misleading. In HTML5, the [W3C requires](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-form-name) **a form's** `name` to be unique in a collection of forms, if any. But the elements' `name`s in a form can be [any non-empty string](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-name) except \__charset\__ and _isindex_.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks a submit button, only that form will be taken in action. Still, it should be better to name them so that you are not confused :)