# cakephp: export filtered data to Excel

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

in my view, I have 2 buttons, one in a form to filter data based on a dropdown list, and another to export the filtered data to Excel.

```
        <?php
            $options = array();
            $options[0] = 'All';
            $options[1] = 'Due last 6 months';
            $options[2] = 'Due current month';
            $options[3] = 'Due next 3 months';
            $options[4] = 'Due next 6 months';
            $options[5] = 'Due next 12 months';            
        ?>

        <div class="row">
            <?= $this->Form->create() ?>
                <fieldset>                
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><?= $this->Form->input('select_period_id', ['options' => $options, 'empty' => false, 'label' => __('Select Period')]) ?></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top:25px;"><?= $this->Form->button(__('Search'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?></div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            <?= $this->Form->end() ?>                
        </div>
    <div class="timetables index large-9 medium-8 columns content">
        <?= $this->Html->link(__('Export to xlsx'), array_merge($this->request->query, ['_ext' => 'xlsx']), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>
```

I assumed that the first button is a POST, and the second is a GET.
I was able to have the filtered data with the first button, but not with the second:

```
$data = $this->request->data;
    $select_period = $this->request->data('select_period_id');
    $today = Time::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    $second_date = Time::now();
    $assetsAssignations = $this->AssetsAssignations->find()
        ->contain(['Assets']);

    if($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) 
    {
        if ($select_period == 0) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('-6 months');                
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
        } elseif ($select_period == 1) {                
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('-6 months');                
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'end_date >=' => $second_date,
                'end_date <=' => $today
                    ]);
             // etc..

    } elseif($this->request->is(['get'])) 
    {
          ???
    }

    $_filename = "xls_report_replacement_" . date('Ymd');
    $this->set(compact('assetsAssignations', '_filename'));        
}
```

I did not find what should I put when it the the export to Excel button (GET).

Any help please ?

_
update: I tried this, and I got an error when opening the excel file

```
{
    $data = $this->request->data;
    $select_period = $this->request->data('select_period_id');
    $today = Time::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    $second_date = Time::now();
    $assetsAssignations = $this->AssetsAssignations->find()
        ->contain('Assets');

    debug($this->request->data);

    if (isset($this->request->data['btn1'])) 
    {
        if ($select_period == 0) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('-6 months');                
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
        } elseif ($select_period == 1) {                
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('-6 months');                
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'Assets.life_end_date >=' => $second_date,
                'Assets.life_end_date <=' => $today
                    ]);
        } elseif ($select_period == 2) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('1 month');
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'Assets.life_end_date >=' => $today,
                'Assets.life_end_date <=' => $second_date
                    ]);

        } elseif ($select_period == 3) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('3 months');
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'Assets.life_end_date >=' => $today,
                'Assets.life_end_date <=' => $second_date
                    ]);
        } elseif ($select_period == 4) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('6 months');
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'Assets.life_end_date >=' => $today,
                'Assets.life_end_date <=' => $second_date
                    ]);
        } elseif ($select_period == 5) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('12 months');
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'Assets.life_end_date >=' => $today,
                'Assets.life_end_date <=' => $second_date
                    ]);
        }
    } elseif (isset($this->request->data['btn2'])) {
        if ($select_period == 0) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('-6 months');                
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
        } elseif ($select_period == 1) {                
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('-6 months');                
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'Assets.life_end_date >=' => $second_date,
                'Assets.life_end_date <=' => $today
                    ]);
        } elseif ($select_period == 2) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('1 month');
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'Assets.life_end_date >=' => $today,
                'Assets.life_end_date <=' => $second_date
                    ]);

        } elseif ($select_period == 3) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('3 months');
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'Assets.life_end_date >=' => $today,
                'Assets.life_end_date <=' => $second_date
                    ]);
        } elseif ($select_period == 4) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('6 months');
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'Assets.life_end_date >=' => $today,
                'Assets.life_end_date <=' => $second_date
                    ]);
        } elseif ($select_period == 5) {
            $second_date = $second_date->modify('12 months');
            $second_date = $second_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $assetsAssignations->where([
                'Assets.life_end_date >=' => $today,
                'Assets.life_end_date <=' => $second_date
                    ]);
        }
        debug($select_period);
        die();
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'test.xlsx']);
    }
    $_filename = "xls_report_replacement_" . date('Ymd');
    $this->set(compact('assetsAssignations', '_filename'));        

}
```

In my view, I included the second button in the form:

```
<div class="row">
            <?= $this->Form->create('form_name') ?>
                <fieldset>                
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><?= $this->Form->input('select_period_id', ['options' => $options, 'empty' => false, 'label' => __('Select Period')]) ?></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top:25px;"><?php echo $this->Form->submit('Search', array('name'=>'btn1'))?></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top:25px;"><?php echo $this->Form->submit('Excel', array('name'=>'btn2'))?></div>

                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            <?= $this->Form->end() ?>

        </div>
```

When I debug with the first button:

```
[
    'select_period_id' => '1',
    'btn2' => 'Excel'
]

select_period_id = '1'
```

Debug with the Excel button:

```
[
    'select_period_id' => '2',
    'btn2' => 'Excel'
]
select_period_id = '2'
```

Comment: You want the data to be filtered when you export to Excel? You need to make that a second Submit button inside the form, with a different name. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377221/two-submit-buttons-with-different-values-in-cakephp) for an example.)

Comment: thanks @GregSchmidt I updated my code above. at the end of the Excel button code, I put "return $this->redirect(['action' => 'test.xlsx']);"
The excel file is generated but I got this error: Excel cannot open the file ... because the file format is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted...

Comment: If you've left the `debug` statements in there, then that output may be included in the Excel output, which would definitely make it invalid.

Comment: thanks. I deleted the debug lines. Now I got the excel. it atill includes all the rows, not the filtered rows with the dropdown

Comment: It looks wrong to me for you to be redirecting to `test.xlsx`. You have a separate action for handling that? You're not passing the posted data to it in the URL. But that seems like the wrong solution anyway; you should handle it in this action (though you might have a separate, private function for generating that output). There's also no need to replicate 100% of your code inside the main `if`. All the setup of the query is the same whether it's Excel output or not, so do that outside the `if`, and only change up the actual output generation inside the `if`.

Comment: <test> is a duplication of my initial code. I created a view test.ctp, another test.ctp under AssetsAssetignations/xlsx folder, and a test function in my controller. I think it correct like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173828/discussion-between-mbenjemaa-and-greg-schmidt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By including debug statements when you're generating an xlsx file, you are corrupting the output. And by redirecting to `test.xlsx` without any parameters, you are losing your posted data. You could mess around with something like this:

```
$this->redirect(['action' => 'test.xlsx', 'select_period_id' => $select_period])
```

But that's ugly. Instead of redirecting, just set the response type like so:

```
$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'xlsx');
```

Also, you have a lot of duplicated code; much of it can be eliminated.

And you shouldn't need to format dates before passing them to the query builder, by switching from the `Time` class to `Date`.

Here's my suggested version:

```
{
    $data = $this->request->data;
    $select_period = $this->request->data('select_period_id');
    $today = FrozenDate::now();
    $assetsAssignations = $this->AssetsAssignations->find()
        ->contain('Assets');

    // This block could be done with a switch instead of if-elseif
    if ($select_period == 0) {
        $start_date = $end_date = null;
    } elseif ($select_period == 1) {                
        // Alternately, $start_date = $today->subMonths(6);
        $start_date = $today->modify('-6 months');
        $end_date = $today;
    } elseif ($select_period == 2) {
        $start_date = $today;
        // Alternately, $start_date = $today->addMonth();
        $end_date = $today->modify('1 month');
    } elseif ($select_period == 3) {
        $start_date = $today;
        // Alternately, $start_date = $today->addMonths(3);
        $end_date = $today->modify('3 months');
    } elseif ($select_period == 4) {
        $start_date = $today;
        $end_date = $today->modify('6 months');
    } elseif ($select_period == 5) {
        $start_date = $today;
        $end_date = $today->modify('12 months');
    }

    if ($start_date) {
        $assetsAssignations->where([
            'Assets.life_end_date >=' => $start_date,
            'Assets.life_end_date <=' => $end_date
        ]);
    }

    // Personally, I'd rename this from btn2 to something like xlsx, here and in the form template
    if (isset($this->request->data['btn2'])) {
        $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'xlsx');
    }

    $_filename = "xls_report_replacement_" . date('Ymd');
    $this->set(compact('assetsAssignations', '_filename'));
}
```

As you can see, much shorter code, and it should be functionally identical.

Update: In the controller, add on top:

```
use Cake\I18n\FrozenDate;
```